# Corrupted Shapefiles when saving edits in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, corrupt

Has anyone experience regular corruption of Shapefiles when saving edits in QGIS?

Since testing the new LTR, we have had regular occurrences of the Shapefile being corrupted, and "_packed" SHP and SHX components appear in the file folder.

I have updated Bug Report [#14711](https://hub.qgis.org/issues/14711) with some details, but so far have no feedback or comment. We were hoping to rollout to the rest of the organisation, but with the current level of file corruption occurring, we cannot risk wider use.

I can reproduce the corruption by having a duplicate copy of the Shapefile open in the QGIS project - NOT in edit mode, just open. I can do the exact same thing with duplicate versions open in previous versions with no corruption at all. I have also seen attributes disappear or change as I saved edits with the attribute table open, indicating some mix-up with record count in the DBF and  the SHX components.

If anyone else has experience similar issues and been able to resolve we would love to hear so that we can continue with the planned roll-out of the new LTR that has so many other improvements.

QGIS version = 2.14.4 (LTR)

Shapefile location = both local C drive and network locations

Comment: Can you provide a sample shapefile that will definitely go crazy while editing?  Maybe you should link from the ticket back here.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 2.14.1 or 2.16.0, shape tested with FME. I have had some similar issues in the past but not very frequent and not sure what version.

Comment: Opening two copies of the same shapefile feels like a bad idea but you must have a reason. Could you explain?

Comment: I was able to reproduce it repeating in testing with new shapefiles every time (to ensure it wasn't related to existing data).... steps taken were (1) create new shapefile, make editable and add a few new features (2) save edits and stop editing (3) duplicate later, neither versions are currently editable (4) make one editable, and make some changes, move/add vertice, add or delete feature (even just one of the above) (4) saves edits.... bang shapefile corrupted and error message on screen  (check issue tracker for message... I'm not at my PC now!) Happened for lines and polygons in a new prj

Comment: As to why we sometimes have multiple versions open... we have some very complex templates for producing plansets. Some plans require a few features to be 'highlighted' above others, so we often have the original full layer at the bottom,  a 'whitewash' layer above and then a highlighted feature layer above that with just some features showing. For SOME plans the same look could be achieve through styling of the the one layer alone, but that was a very very simplified summary of the project, we often need to bring the highlighted features above other layers, so it needs to be a duplicate.

Comment: As I mentioned in the issue tracker, we have not seen this issue until v2.14 where some of the changes to shapefile saving were implemented  (they may have been introduced in 2.12 but we weren't allowed to use it so our previous version was 2.10). And if it is such a 'bad idea' and qgis can't handle it, then at least shouldn't it flag a warning that you are about to edit a layer that has more than one copy open or better still simply lock the layer from editing (perhaps with a message as to why) so that users can't accidentally corrupt their files.

Comment: If parallel working on the same file is necessary, you might think of leaving the outdated shapefile database concept, and move to spatialite or postgis databases.

Comment: That might be ideal, but right now that's not really an option. Either way, it doesn't explain why this behavior has started happening since v2.10? And we have no issue if you simply can't edit shapefiles when a duplicate it open, but surely it would be in everyone's bests interests to warn users if they try or simply put a lock on files preventing actions that result in corruption? It's easy for me to advise users not to edit when they have more than 1 version of a file open, but its very easy for people to forget or not even realise and destroy their data.

Comment: Did you think that it worked correctly before? If you open copy_a and copy_b, edit copy_b and save, isn't the copy_a then invalid because it does not contain the edited geometries? If user now starts editing copy_a and save, the edits made into copy_b are lost. But I agree that QGIS should not corrupt shapefiles in such situation.

Comment: Absolutely sure it worked previously without issue - in both 2.8 and 2.10 (we were never allowed to use 2.12). To be honest when we started using qgis and setting up the templates, i also thought it wasn't something that should be able to be done, but after thorough testing it never caused an issue so we figured it had ways to handle it.